# Hibernate Query Language: selecting some properties requires alias name

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

There are 3 classes in picture here:
`Employee.java`, `Department.java`, and `Designation.java`

Here are the partial definitions of each...

*Department.java*

```
public class Department implements java.io.Serializable
{   private Integer id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters for all propreties
}
```

*Designation.java*

```
public class Designation implements java.io.Serializable
{   private Integer id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters for all propreties
}
```

*Employee.java*

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{   private Integer id;
    private Employee reportingOfficer;
    private Department department;
    private Designation designation;
    private String loginId;
    // getters & setters for all propreties
}
```

I tried an HQL query that looked like this:

**1st query**

```
SELECT
  reportingOfficer
FROM
  data.persistence.ordb.Employee
WHERE
  department.name = 'Inventory Control'
  AND
  designation.name = 'Assistant Manager'
```

It gave me an error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid Path: 'department.name'
```

But, I get correct results when I used an alias for `data.persistence.ordb.Employee`, as shown below:

**2nd query**

```
SELECT
  e.reportingOfficer
FROM
  data.persistence.ordb.Employee e
WHERE
  e.department.name = 'Inventory Control'
  AND
  e.designation.name = 'Assistant Manager'
```

Also, I do not get the `Invalid Path` error when I use this 3rd query: (Query that selects `loginId` of type `String` of `reportingOfficer` without alias name for `Employee`)

**3rd query**

```
SELECT
  reportingOfficer.loginId
FROM
  data.persistence.ordb.Employee
WHERE
  department.name = 'Inventory Control'
  AND
  designation.name = 'Assistant Manager'
```

But I get the same `Invalid Path` error when I use this 4th query: (intended to select `designation` of type `Designation` of `reportingOfficer` without alias name for `Employee`)

**4th query**

```
SELECT
  reportingOfficer.designation
FROM
  data.persistence.ordb.Employee
WHERE
  department.name = 'Inventory Control'
  AND
  designation.name = 'Assistant Manager'
```

And this 5th query gives correct results: (selects `designation` of type `Designation` of `reportingOfficer` with alias name for `Employee`)

**5th query**

```
SELECT
  e.reportingOfficer.designation
FROM
  data.persistence.ordb.Employee e
WHERE
  e.department.name = 'Inventory Control'
  AND
  e.designation.name = 'Assistant Manager'
```

My question is: Why the alias name is needed in case of 2nd & 5th queries, but not in 3rd query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

Both the entity you select from (Entity) and the entity you want to project (reportingOfficer) belong to the same entity type: Employee.

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
    private Employee reportingOfficer;
}
```

If you don't use an alias, Hibernate will not know which "department" you are referring to. Is it the one you select from or the one you want to select (reportingOfficer).

My golden rule is to always use aliases even when not necessary.

**Not using aliases is like relying on [operator order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) instead of using parenthesis.**

Comment: In this case of `reportingOfficer.loginId` how hibernate now from where `reportingOfficer` get referred?

Comment: The FROM  clause is the starting point (e.g. the ROOT) and it can locate "[ROOT].reportingOfficer.loginId". When specifying "department" it can be [ROOT].department or [ROOT].reportingOfficer.department, so there's the ambiguity.